# Create aws redshift serverless using cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-redshift-serverless

Can anyone share a basic template to create redshift serverless cluster. It include creating namespace, workgroup. I tried with following template however it's giving error as

```
At least one Resources member must be defined
```

Here is the template I used

```
{
    "Type": "AWS::RedshiftServerless::Workgroup",
    "Properties": {
        "BaseCapacity": 8,
        "ConfigParameters": [
            "ConfigParameter"
        ],
        "EnhancedVpcRouting": "No",
        "NamespaceName": "sample",
        "Port": 5439,
        "PubliclyAccessible": "Yes",
        "SecurityGroupIds": [
            "sg-0d84ef5a0ddb2a5f0"
        ],
        "SubnetIds": [
            "subnet-06860f6313fb01dea",
            "subnet-052ac63eb2d56e361",
            "subnet-0e80ec9a22484bc21"
        ],
        "Tags": [
            "Tag"
        ],
        "WorkgroupName": "sample-wg"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the entirety of your template file? If yes, then you need to read the _Getting Started_ section of the CloudFormation user guide, and follow the exercises.

Comment: I have added resource as follows and it worked for me:  

`Resources:
  RedshiftServerlessWorkgroup:
`